# Insert records from temp table where record is not already preset fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to insert from temporary table into regular one but since there is data in temp table sharing the same values for a primary key of the table I am inserting to, it fails with primary key constraint being violated. That is expected so I am working around it by inserting only the rows that have the primary key not already present in table I am inserting to.

I tried both EXISTS and *NOT IN* approach, I checked examples showcasing both, confirmed both works in SQL server 2014 in general, yet I am still getting the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.InsuranceObjects'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.InsuranceObjects'. The duplicate
>   key value is (3835fd7c-53b7-4127-b013-59323ea35375).

Here is the SQL in *NOT IN* variance I tried:

```
print 'insert into InsuranceObjects'
INSERT INTO $(destinDB).InsuranceObjects
        (
        Id, Value, DefInsuranceObjectId 
        )
SELECT Id, InsuranceObjectsValue, DefInsuranceObjectId
FROM #vehicle v
WHERE v.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM $(destinDB).InsuranceObjects) -- prevent error when running scrypt multiple times over
GO
```

If not apparent:

- Id is the primary key in question.
- $(destinDB) is command line variable. Different from TSQL variable.
  It allows me to define the target database and instance in convenient
  script based level or even multiple scripts based level. Its used in
  multiple variations throughout the code and has so far performed
  perfectly. The only downside is you have to run in CMD mode.
- when creating all temp tables USE $(some database) is also used so
  it's not an issue

I must be missing something completely obvious but it's driving me nuts that such a simple query fails. What is worse, when I try running select without insert part, it returns ALL the records from temp table despite me having confirmed there are duplicates that should fail the *NOT IN* part in where clause.

Comment: If you take out the command line variable and run it in SSMS, do you also get the same problem then?

Comment: @TabAlleman I just hardcoded that database.instance and run in regular mode and, sadly, same results.

Comment: does "regular mode" mean you ran it in SSMS?   If not, please try.   If you get the problem in SSMS, then please post a script that reproduces the issue in SSMS.

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes. Both are actualy run in SSMS, only in case with CMD level variables you need to run it in SQLCMD Mode, it's an option in Query dropdown on top. I would have posted testable version but it's considerably more code (temp table vehicles is made of 3 diff tables with a lot of things on top - 60 lines total only for it's definition and filling) so to put an entire testable environment I woudl be several pages long. some 8 tables in total with models and data filling.

Comment: Do you have duplicate ID values in your temp table?

Comment: @SeanLange - That's a great point. I was quite sure I did but never put that constraint on the temp table. I did now but nothing changed.

Comment: Well unless we can reproduce this issue there isn't much anybody can do. The error message gives you the value that is failing....dig into that value and figure out why it is in the select statement.

Comment: Forgot to save before reruning the tamp table fix, I feel so stupid, @SeanLange you were correct. Merging from different sources I have duplicates in temp table and you were on point! TY so much! Post that as an answer so I can award you for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you have duplicate ID values in your temp table. Please check the values there as it would cause the issue you are seeing.